# Angular ngIf issue (IE11)

Tags: angular

I have an issue with ngIf (ngswitch, ngstyle and other things what can hide or display element)
So the issue is simple. In IE11 every condition that uses a variable from .ts file gets only the first value.

In my case, I need to show loader when a request to the server is sent and when I receive the answer I should hide it. I have a component

```
<my-loader-example-component *ngIf="someService.isRequestInProcess"></my-loader-example-component>
```

When I send a request I change `isRequestInProcess` to true and in Chrome it works correctly (loader showing), but in IE is not. I tried a lot of solutions but nothing works (ngswhich, ngstyle, ngclass).....

P.S. No errors in the console

Angular: 11;
IE11 support is enabled

UPD: __________
I tried to use custom directive for `*ngIf` and i found that the directive calls only ONCE in IE11

Comment: which  version of angular? have you [enabled](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support#configuring-angular-cli-for-compatibility-with-ie11) support? Also, the support will be [dropped in angular v13](https://angular.io/guide/deprecations#internet-explorer-11)

Comment: also check `.browserslistrc` file, you need to turn on support for the IE 11

Comment: @SurajRao Angular 11, yes i enabled IE11 support

Comment: check please `polyfills.ts` as well

Comment: I saw this line in polifill.ts

Comment: @AshotAleqsanyan tell me please what i should check there?? i didn't got any error....

Comment: /** IE11 requires the following for NgClass support on SVG elements */
// import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.

Comment: oh wait please, I think I am wrong

Comment: any updates? could you resolve the problem? also, can you please try to run your code on a different laptop?

Comment: yes i've solve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with including shadydom polyfill, and it's broke all directives

Answer (score 1):

*ngIf often has issues in IE for some reason. Whenever I want a loader, I just create a hidden class and use that.

```
.hidden {
    display: none; 
 }
```

And in your component:

```
<my-loader-example-component 
[class.hidden]="!(someService.isRequestInProcess)">

</my-loader-example-component>
```

Display set to none does't always have to happen. You can tweak it to behave differently e.g 0 opacity, invisible, full-height, full-width, etc etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, that solution works the same, it just get the first value of someService.isRequestInProcess so it just always hidden or always showing

Comment: Then I would suggest either hiding/showing it manually, or use a Behavior Subject from RXJS to create a Boolean observable.